# View controller loses unwind segue if storyboard initialviewcontroller changed

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue, ios11, xcode9

I don't know if it's a common behaviour or if i'm missing something but i'm unable to perform an unwind segue in my viewController if the viewcontroller that defines the segue it's not in the hierarchy. To make myself clear:

1) In the `AppDelegate` i changed the initialviewcontroller based on the simple condition if the user i logged.

```
if (user.isLogged()) {
  skipLogin()
}
```

2) If YES skip the `LoginViewController` (the one that defines the unwind segue) and go to the `MainViewController`. If NOT nothing changes as the `LoginViewController` is the default initialViewController for the storyboard.

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "main")
window?.rootViewController = vc
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

3) When i trigger the logout action in the main view controller, the `performSegue` method is called (the identifier itself is found) but nothing happens.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error

Answer (score 1):

It is common behaviour.

Unwind segues are different from normal segues. Unwind Segue always perform the segue from your current view controller or source view controller to an existing view controller, a view controller that is already present in the navigation stack. It does not explicitly define any destination view controller. A unwind segue searches for it's destination view controller at runtime by traversing the navigation hierarchy.

So in your case, `LoginViewController` that defines the segue, is not present in the navigation hierarchy if `YES`. For this reason, segue is not working.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if there is a way to check if a segue will perform or maybe the best solution is to set the rootviewcontroller instead of performing the segue?!